# visual studio 2010 fsproj not supported

Tags: visual-studio-2010, f#

I have Visual Studio 2010 at home and at another location. I tried running a fsproj project from home at this other location and when I open the sollution it says it is not supported. I have other csharp project in the solution and these load just fine.
Does anyone have any ideas why this happens and how can I make this error go away?

Thank you.

Comment: With which version of visual studio did you try to open your solution at this other location ? If it was VS 2010, did it have F# installed ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have F# installed? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/fsharp/default

Comment: I understand that any version of VS2010 will do and I have that but if I click Help->About I see that F# isn't there. So should I install F# stand alone?

Comment: At my place, VS10 ->about shows: Microsoft Visual F# 2010. So I think you need to install the CTP; http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=effc5bc4-c3df-4172-ad1c-bc62935861c5&displaylang=en

Answer (score 1):

Rerun the VS2010 installer and add the F# support.

Answer (score 0):

.fsproj files are apparently Visual F# project files.

To make this error go away make sure that you have the F# bits of Visual Studio 2010 installed.